# Where can I ask this question about webmail security features?

Tags: support, specific-question, site-recommendation

I'm not sure which Stack Exchange site I should use for this GMail/Yahoo! mail security question:

> Let's say I have a GMail or Yahoo!
>   account and another person knows my
>   password. (I had to tell him the
>   password because both of us are using
>   the same account for a common
>   purpose.)
>
> Now, is there are way, like some paid
>   service of Yahoo! or GMail or
>   whatever, that tells you right away
>   when the password was changed by that
>   other person? For example, it could
>   send e-mails to your alternative
>   e-mail addresses when you change the
>   password.
>
> **But**, what if the other person logs in, deletes my alternate e-mail
>   addresses and changes the password one
>   day, and I am unable to log in to that
>   account? I'll be screwed.
>
> So how do I make sure that I never
>   lose access to my e-mail accounts? Is
>   there any paid service for this
>   purpose? I have been Googling, but it
>   has been in vain.

Comment: This question now exists on Web Apps: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/12395/question-about-security-featurespassword-recovery-in-gmail-yahoo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try asking on http://webapps.stackexchange.com.